# Sqlite MATCH and Subquery

Tags: sql, sqlite, match

I wrote the following query that works as expected:

```
SELECT col1 FROM table1 WHERE col1 MATCH ‘linux’;
```

My problem is that, instead of using a predefined word such as ‘linux’,  I wish to get it  from a subquery such as (select OS from table2):

so I wrote the following code:

```
SELECT col1 FROM table1 WHERE col1  MATCH (SELECT os FROM table2);
```

but it doesn’t work as expected, as it seems the the subquery (select OS from table2) returns just one row instead of a list of words.

any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

If you have enabled the [enhanced query syntax](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_2), you could search for multiple words like this:

```
SELECT col1
FROM table1
WHERE col1 MATCH 'foo OR bar OR baz ...'
```

To construct such a string, use [group_concat](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#groupconcat):

```
SELECT col1
FROM table1
WHERE col1 MATCH (SELECT group_concat(os, ' OR ')
                  FROM table2)
```